# T/SQL EXECUTE AS, if error 0x5, revert

Tags: t-sql, try-catch, execute

I'm currently writing a special report in T/SQL.

Basicly, I've got a table containing windows usernames, and I have to run a stored procedure once for each person (Using a cursor). This can easily be done using the `EXECUTE AS USER = 'domain\username'`. However, if a user loses his windows login after the table is generated, i get the following error:

```
  Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\user', error code 0x5.
```

This error stops the procedure completely, which will give me an error. Is there a way to ignore this message and just skip to the next cursor value?

In advance, thanks
Gunnar S. Knudsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL 2005 or higher, you can use [TRY...CATCH (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Here's the example from the provided link:

```
-- Verify that the stored procedure does not already exist.
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'usp_GetErrorInfo', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo;
GO

-- Create procedure to retrieve error information.
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo
AS
SELECT
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
GO

BEGIN TRY
    -- Generate divide-by-zero error.
    SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.
    EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: I'll be darned, Have tried that very same solution, but had forgot to use REVERT afterwards...

(If anyone else got same issue, the revert needs to be made before the usp_GetErrorInfo is executed [or give the relevant user rights for it])